# Filter Json output using C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, filter

I am getting a json result via HTTPClient request using C#, the output will look like mentioned below

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "username": "abcdefghi",
    "password": "oiwenkwjw"
  }
}
```

I need to filter only "data" object using C# in a static class, I have no problem in using LINQ or any other simple method, but no need to create a separate class for it, any small help will be much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;  -- i used newtonsoft json api

string jsonData = @"{  
    'status': 1,
    'message': '',
    'data': {
    'username': 'abcdefghi',
    'password': 'oiwenkwjw'
    }
    }";

var details = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
Console.WriteLine(details["data"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also define some classes to model your JSON:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the JSON and output `Data` from the overridden `ToString()` method:

```
string jsonData = @"{  
    'status': 1,
    'message': '',
    'data': {
        'username': 'abcdefghi',
        'password': 'oiwenkwjw'
     }
 }";

 var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);

 Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson.Data);
```

Output:

```
{
    "Username": "abcdefghi",
    "Password": "oiwenkwjw"
}
```